# Нужна ли запятая перед и, если после союза идёт слово "если"

Tags: пунктуация

Поэтому он любил играть в футбол, и если точно бил по мячу, то обычно забивал гол.

Нужно ли поставить запятую после слова "футбола" и почему? (что тут за правило)

Answer (score 4):

По-моему, союз "и" соединяет здесь однородные сказуемые "любил играть" и "забивал", поэтому запятая не нужна. В подобного рода предложениях проблема обычно состоит в том, надо ли ставить запятую после "и". Здесь не надо, так как имеется вторая часть составного союза "если...то"

Comment: Спасибо...

Answer (score 0):

Поэтому он любил играть в ФУТБОЛ, и если точно бил по мячу, то обычно забивал гол. Запятая после футбол не нужна, так как любил играть и забивал - однородные сказуемые. Запятая после если тоже не нужна.
Два стоящих рядом союза (неважно сочинительных или подчинительных) всегда разделяются между собой запятой. Эта запятая НЕ ставится, если далее идёт вторая часть составного союза ТО, ТАК, НО. Пример. Капли падали с весла,и,когда они капали, на воде появлялись круги.Сравните. Капли падали с весла,и__когда они капали, ТО на воде появлялись круги.